# Xcode / phonegap - make new version

Tags: xcode, cordova

I have a working app using Xcode/phonegap. It's in the store in version 1.

What is the best way to make version 2 ?

Do I need to create a new project ? If so, can I inherit from all the things I've specified in version 1 ?

Thank you.

Xcode Version 4.6.1 - Phonegap 2.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the version of your project you need to

1. Open project
2. Go to Resources
3. Open -Info.plist
4. Change bundle version string

You can also edit this file without opening the project.
The file is in the  folder, sibling with the www folder.